# Add text to iconbutton flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i add text next to icon in my flutter?

Here is my code down below

```
actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.black,
        ), 
        onPressed: () async {
          widget.selectedList.productsAndStatus.clear();
          await ProductsList.editSavedListName(widget.selectedList, widget.selectedListIndex);
          setState(() {});
        }
      )
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
         Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    widget.selectedList.productsAndStatus.clear();
                    await ProductsList.editSavedListName(widget.selectedList, widget.selectedListIndex);
                    setState(() {});
                  }
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5,),
              Text("Your text")
            ],
          )
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `TextButton.icon()` and add `icon` and `label` that you need

```dart
TextButton.icon(
   onPressed: () {},
   icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
   label: const Text('Delete item'),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `actions` property is the [actions](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/actions.html) property of the `AppBar` widget.

You can add the text next to the `IconButton` in the `actions` List like this:

```
actions: [
      IconButton(
       ... 
      ),
      Text('Flutter')
    ],
```

Comment: Sure, you can add text there though. `actions` takes a list of widgets and `Text` is a widget. Try it, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is my full code

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    elevation: 0.0,
    iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.grey[600],
    ),
    leading: GestureDetector(
      child: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back_ios,
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    ),
    title: Text(
      '${widget.selectedList.listName}',
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.grey[700],
        fontSize: 25.0,
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
      ),
    ),
    centerTitle:  true,
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.black,
        ), 
        
        onPressed: () async {
          widget.selectedList.productsAndStatus.clear();
          await ProductsList.editSavedListName(widget.selectedList, widget.selectedListIndex);
          setState(() {});
        }
      )
    ],
  ),
```